# How to access a specific product directly in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a product list. There are 3 products in my product list. Each product has its own id, so when I click a product, the id will be passed to my product details (/product/samsung). In my product details page, I will fetch all data of products from an url link ( /product/1 ).

Thus, if I want to access the product details page directly from google without choosing the product in my website, how can I pass the id of product to the product details page? Because the page does not get the id of product, I am not able to fetch all data of products from the url link (/product/1).

Could anyone help me for this case?

Thank you

Comment: You should give some more information such as: are you using a client-side router (e.g. React Router) or if not, why can't you simply *parse* the URL when the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, I am using a client-side router.  I am not clear with your question "why can't you simply parse the URL when the page is loaded?". I can access the URL when I choose the product in the product list page. The url link of the product details page will be (http://localhost:3000/product/samsung). When choosing the product, the id of product is passed to the product details page. Based on the id of product, I can fetch all details of product such as: prize, resolution etc.

Comment: However, if I access the page directly, the product details page will not have the id of product, so the page can not fetch all details of product due to missing the id of product.

Comment: How do you know to fetch `/product/1` when user clicks on `sumsung`?

Comment: You should use a url like /product/1/samsung instead of /product/samsung. That way it is both SEO friendly as well as has all the input necessary to fetch the data for the page. The parts of the URL are available to the react-router as state values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually, the flow should go like this. If you click on an item you should go to **products/:id**, where the details of that particular product are shown followed by one API request for getting details for that particular product. Lets call this page **ProductDetails** page. This Rest API call should be present in the **componentDidMount** lifecycle method of ProductDetails page. In this case it doesn't matter how you reached this page, if :id is present in URL, it will request and show the results.

Comment: Awesome Ajay. Thanks for your help so much. Now it is working as I expect

Comment: @Kevin Please accept the answer, if it's solved your problem.